# Solving equations with interdependent variables & functions when data is in bits

Tags: function, math, equation-solving, linear-equation, boolean-algebra

How to solve 2 equations with two variables when functions are involved and data is in bits ?

Equation 1:

f +i + constant data =reed solomon function (h+contant data)

Equation 2:

h +i + constant data = reed solomon function ( f + constant data)

where f,h,i are bits (boolean array) and constant data are also bits (boolean array) Constant data is known

left hand side is 56 bits right hand side (inside function ) is 152 bits

tried brute force approach but it takes forever and does not work .

hint i found online : have to use gaussian elimination method but not sure of this approach

Comment: Better convert those bits to numbers.  Solvers for simultaneous equations will expect them.  I would not recommend gaussian elimination.  Lu decomposition is a better choice.

Comment: @duffymo . The real problem is how to solve a pair of equations when there is a function involved on the RHas having a variable as an input parameter . Also the "+" symbols are not additions but say that these bits belong together

Comment: That means that the solution is non-linear.  You need to express the problem in terms of increments. Make an initial guess, calculate an increment, and iterate until the results converge.

Comment: That's exactly what bruteforce is and it will take forever (2^36) . Took more than 7 hrs after which i terminated it

Comment: Non linear is not brute force.